# Custom ROM Samsung SM-G53OT1

Tags: rom, samsung-galaxy, custom-rom

I've been using this phone a while, and I have been through tough times with it. Two bootloops, Google Play Services crashing infinitely, weird errors, everything. I'd say I've "bonded" with this Samsung and would like to take it up a notch.

I've been looking everywhere for ROMS for this phone and I haven't been able to find any, not figure out how. Maybe I'm just stupid but man it's aggregating.

I have a PC, Samsung driver's, Odin, and of course, my Samsung. I have everything I *believe* is necessary to flash a custom ROM.

I would appreciate ANY help to get a nice ROM for my phone.

At the minimum, I'd like it to have a theme changer.

Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime One
SM-G53OT1

Answer (score 0):

You can install CM 13 on  your SM G5series
CM 13 is a custom ROM used in android devices.

- your warranty will be void if you install a custom rom.
- careful that installing a custom ROM would sometimes injure your device
  permanently.
- Follow these steps to root your device to enjoy vast features

  Download a recovery.img,USB driver and ADB tools for your corresponding device(extract and install them and keep the extracted file in one folder)

Download and Copy the zipped cm13 and gapps6(arm)to your device's internal or SD storage

- Connect your device to a PC in USB debugging mode(just tap  7 times on the developer options in settings to enable USB debugging)
- open program files,open minimal adb tools.Type CMD in location bar to open the command prompt in that folder)
- type "adb devices" in the CMD without quotes.
- "fastboot recovery.img"
  Your device will be reboot and
  Team win recovery is opened
- wipe the system ,cache,dalvik cache
- select INSTALL from the option
- choose the zipped file cm13 and swipe it to flash the custom ROM.
- choose the zipped file gaapps and flash it by swiping.

Your device will be updated to marshmallow after rebooting